# Matching characters until pattern using re

Tags: python

I am trying to use python regex to match all the character between `'['` and `'] '` (note the extra space).  Initially I had naively matched `([^])` and then consumed the space, but in one of my test cases there are `]` characters.  My example string is

```
127.0.0.1 - dgm [Thu Oct  2 09:55:11 2014] [9 <?xml version="1.0"?><action><signal><composite id="1" data="atm_te" format="generic" exp_number_start="12000" exp_number_end="0" pass_start="-1" pass_end="-1"><composite_dim dimid="0" dim="atm_r" to_dim="0" format="generic" /></composite><documentation id="1" exp_number_start="12000" exp_number_end="0" pass_start="-1" pass_end="-1"><description>YAG TS Te Profile</description><label>Te</label><units>[eV]</units><dimension dimid="0"><label>Major Radius</label><units>[m]</units></dimension><dimension dimid="1"><label>Time</label><units>[s]</units></dimension></documentation></signal></action> 13500 0   0 XML MAST MAST ] 0 20872 [] 44.909000 6 6 [25837 7417]
```

So I have tried using lookahead using the regex

```
(?P<host>\s|\S+)\s?- (?P<username>\s|\S+)\s?\[(?P<datetime>[^]]*)\]\s\[(?P<query>.*(?=\]\s))\]\s
```

but this seem to overmatch both in my code and in pythex web page.

The result for the *query* group that I am looking for is

```
"9 <?xml version="1.0"?><action><signal><composite id="1" data="atm_te" format="generic" exp_number_start="12000" exp_number_end="0" pass_start="-1" pass_end="-1"><composite_dim dimid="0" dim="atm_r" to_dim="0" format="generic" /></composite><documentation id="1" exp_number_start="12000" exp_number_end="0" pass_start="-1" pass_end="-1"><description>YAG TS Te Profile</description><label>Te</label><units>[eV]</units><dimension dimid="0"><label>Major Radius</label><units>[m]</units></dimension><dimension dimid="1"><label>Time</label><units>[s]</units></dimension></documentation></signal></action> 13500 0   0 XML MAST MAST "
```

(and yes the trailing white space is important)

Comment: *"overmatch"*? I don't see *any* match: https://regex101.com/r/wM1fO0/1. Why is the trailing space important? Would https://regex101.com/r/wM1fO0/2 do what you need?

Comment: I am using the trailing space to distinguish between the end of the _query_ group and a _]_ within the signal group.  I will try the website you suggest, but it works on [pythex](http://pythex.org/)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain what you're looking for (and why, so we can rule out [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731)).

Comment: *Why* is the trailing white space important? Also the second link in my first comment gets that match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Comment: The last trailing white space is important as it indicates a missing field.  However, your solution worked fine.  What I don't understand is why using lookahead matched the 'next' pattern (i.e. the one after the one I was hoping to find).  Thanks for the help anyway